# Derivative at the point

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How can I get a derivate at the point? I've specifyed a boundary condition for my PDE:

```
  lb = - c D[u[x, t], x][a, t] + d u[a, t] == gamma
```

When I present the function as

```
a = 0;
c = 1; d= 3;
u[x_, t_] = f[x, t] w[x]
f[x_, t_] = E^(-k t) + 1; 
    k = 5;
w[x_] = x^2 Cos[x];
```

and try to express the right part:

```
Solve[lb, gamma]
```

I get

```
{{gamma -> -(2 (1 + E^(-5 t)) x Cos[x] - (1 + E^(-5 t)) x^2 Sin[
     x])[0, t]}}
```

So, variables x and t are still free. But I want *Mathematica* to substitute x=0 , t=t and get {gamma ->0} above.

Comment: What do you mean substitute `x=0`? Have you looked at `DSolve[]`?

Comment: No, this is no ODE.  I'll use gamma gotten above to simulate the solution I've pointed explicitly. I just take a derivate here , nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = 0;
c = 1;
d = 3;
k = 5;
f[x_, t_] = E^(-k t) + 1;
w[x_] = x^2 Cos[x];
u[x_, t_] = f[x, t] w[x];
```

I don't understand what you mean by the notation `D[u[x, t], x][a, t]` in the definition of `lb`. Since `D[u[x, t], x]` is not a [`pure function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html), it does not take arguments. Assuming that the definition of `lb` should read

```
lb = -c D[u[x, t], x] + d u[a, t] == gamma

(*  -2 (1 + E^(-5 t)) x Cos[x] + (1 + E^(-5 t)) x^2 Sin[x] == gamma  *)

soln = Solve[lb, gamma][[1]] // Simplify

(*  {gamma -> E^(-5 t) (1 + E^(5 t)) x (-2 Cos[x] + x Sin[x])}  *)

lb /. soln // Simplify

(*  True  *)
```

If instead you mean

```
lb = -c (D[u[x, t], x] /. x -> a) + d u[a, t] == gamma

(*  0 == gamma  *)
```

Alternatively, you can write the derivative as

```
lb = -c Derivative[1, 0][u][a, t] + d u[a, t] == gamma

(*  0 == gamma  *)
```

Comment: As I understand the question, the last line is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Thank you. Replace /. is what I need.